# Removing Back Stack entries in winrt

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

How  can i remove back stack entries in Windows 8 xaml - C# application. I found a similar question here in stackoverflow. But any of the answer provided conatins a clear way to achieve the functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is answered here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/5383710c-0bf6-4fa5-9bd0-2cb4e8754f61

In short, it's not supported. It can be done with a workaround but that workaround could change in a future release.

Dev support, design support and more awesome goodness on the way: http://bit.ly/winappsupport

Answer (score 1):

A way to solve this would be to get your frame, and remove the last entry from its BackStack, like so:

```
mainFrame.BackStack.Remove(mainFrame.BackStack.LastOrDefault());
```